# how can i draw line in UIMapView?I have two distinct latitude and Longitude?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

i have two latitude and longitude. one is current latitude,longitude and second i get from web service now by using both i want to draw a path between this two so what should i do?i have no idea about it.Please help me....Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [this](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108) page.

Comment: hi!I have seen this example but here it takes latitude and longitude from specific file and i have only 2 latitude and 2 longitude so how can i adjust.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.kadirpekel.com/2010/05/30/drawing_routes_onto_mkmapview_using_unofficial_google_maps_directions_api/

it's also good Result